# Is it possible to delete a changeset on codeplex?

Tags: codeplex

I'm trying codeplex and polluted it with fake changesets using subversion. I'd like to delete them now. Is it possible ?

Comment: as your login name... asksuperuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's information on removing a changeset on CodePlex: http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Removing%20a%20changeset%20from%20source%20control

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible but you could contact the team...
http://codeplex.codeplex.com/discussions/26335